# Config file in haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like to be able to provide to my Haskell app and config file written in Haskell. The reason why is because I would like the user to be able to provide a few custom functions.

Is it possible to load a haskell file at runtime, even though it might depend on some type provided by the app itself.

At the moment, I have a super main function, and I build a new executable per config file. The file basically, declares some hooks and call super main with them. The problem with that is, at the moment I have to define a new target for each config in my cabal file (I use a sandbox, and  I don't want to have to install any library part of my package). I thought using runghc instead but I do I make it works with the sandbox ? I've seen there is a 'plugin' package on hackage but it does't seem to be up to date. What is the common way to deal with this type of problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dyre](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dyre-0.8.12/docs/Config-Dyre.html) looks like it fits the bill.

Comment: I'm more thinking fo passing the config file as a parameter , so I can chose which one to use. Does dyre as such options ?

Comment: @mb14 If you look at the documentation, you will soon know the answer exactly as well as I do.